QT not responding to touch event with external touch screen
I am trying to use an HMDI/USB touchscreen with a QT application on Ubuntu. I am able to use the touchscreen to navigate in the OS, but my QT application is completely unresponsive to the touch events.
The application type is a Desktop QT 6.8.1 with a simple button:

This is the content of my mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents, true);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_pressed()
{
    qDebug() << "button pressed";
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_released()
{
    qDebug() << "button released";
}

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent* event)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
        qDebug() << "touch!";
        return true;
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
        qDebug() << "touch end!";
        return true;
    case QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick:
        qDebug() << "double click";
        return true;
    case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
        qDebug() << "pressed";
        return true;
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        qDebug() << "released";
        return true;
    default:
        // call base implementation
        return QMainWindow::event(event);
    }
}

I am enabling touch events in the constructor. When I run the application, I can see the events debug messages when using the mouse. However, when using the touchscreen, none of the events are triggered. Not even the mouse ones!
Is there a reason why the touch event are not recognized?
Note: touch events are working completely fine on another UI framework (flutter).

Does tapping on the button trigger those functions (assuming they're properly set as slots and they also work when using the mouse)?

@musicamante yes, but only with the mouse. not with the touchscreen.

@AhmedAEK It should still print a debug message if the event is triggered at all no?

Note that you're using a QMainWindow with an UI set, which means that it has a central widget. Since you only set the attribute on the main window, the central widget will receive the event as a mouse event, and will then propagate it to the main window as such. As far as I know, in this case the event is not "restored" as a touch event, even if it wasn't accepted by the children. Try setting the attribute to the central widget and the button as well.

Is touch screen functional otherwise? It needs a correct configuration. Desktop and X11 should react on that. Also, HID-compatible driver for touch screen generates normal pointer events, including mouse ones, that goes to central widget, not to main window.

@Swift-FridayPie yes as stated in the question, i can navigate the desktop environment and use flutter applications with it. If it was seen as a mouse, shouldn't the same event as when i use the mouse be triggered?

@ESD Try installing an event filter on the QApplication and check its output (printing the event types) when using the touch screen. Test that also without setting the attribute. Also add more detailed information about the OS and window manager, and relevant environment/building data, such as how Qt was installed/configured/built, etc.
